# has value in a console but it's nil in my controller and my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this strange behavior and I don't undertand why. Here is the thing:

I have this record in my payment model:

```
1.9.3p286 :019 > u.payment.last
  Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = 10
 => [#<Payment id: 37, bank_name: "Mercantil", plan: "Plan Uno", date: "2012-12-25", reference_number: "3452435", coupon: "", user_id: 10, created_at: "2012-12-25 21:56:12", updated_at: "2012-12-25 21:58:31", active_until: "2013-01-24">]
```

As you can see, I have one record for my user: 10.

If I try to get the same information in my controller I don't get any exception, but

```
@user.payment.last.active_until
```

is empty, the same in the view.

For example if I try this in my view:

```
<%= @user.payment.last.active_until %>
```

I didn't get anything, is blank.

If I try this

```
<%= @user.payment %>
```

I got the same as my console

```
[#<Payment id: 37, bank_name: "Mercantil", plan: "Plan Uno", date: "2012-12-25", reference_number: "3452435", coupon: "", user_id: 10, created_at: "2012-12-25 21:56:12", updated_at: "2012-12-25 21:58:31", active_until: "2013-01-24">, #<Payment id: nil, bank_name: nil, plan: nil, date: nil, reference_number: nil, coupon: nil, user_id: 10, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, active_until: nil>]
```

I really don't understand what happend here. Any help please.

Thanks in advance.

PD: The user could has many payments, but I need just the last.

Comment: Why do you have a singular association (`payment`) that returns multiple objects?

Comment: I'm sorry Gareth, you mean something like @user.payment???

Comment: Yes, why have you called your association `payment` in the singular, if there can be many of them? The standard convention is to say "`has_many :payments`" so that you can write "`@user.payments`" (which is more descriptive)

Comment: Well I use this scaffold rails generate scaffol Payment and them the scaffold create the model "payment"

Comment: That's ok. If you write `has_many :payments` in the `User` model, Rails knows that you're referring to the `Payment` model, because it knows how to take the word `payments` and singularize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same as in your console. In the console you get have one record, but in the view you get two - the record that you see in the console, and another blank one.

I'm guessing the blank one is the one that you are using for the `form` tag helper for the form used to create a new `Payment` record, but that's also the one that `last` returns. Either take the one before last, or filter for saved records before you call `last`.

Comment: Look again - the `@user.payment` array contains two entries. The first is your record - the one with id 37 - and the other one has `nil` for all the fields(including ID) except for `user_id`. This is an unsaved record - it's not inside the database and you won't be able to obtain it using `Payment.all` - it was created by `@user.payment.create` or `@user.payment.build`, and until you save it - it only exists inside `@user.payment`.

Comment: Right, but your output has two `Payment` objects. You must be creating one in your controller action

Comment: Oh I see, but I don't know how to get the information just from the last that have information. Could you help me please

Comment: That's one option. You can also use something like `@user.payment.select{|e|e.id}.last`, or just get the last record in the controller before the new record is created.

Comment: Idan I created a before_create method but I still get and empty record

Comment: The `before_create` method has nothing to do with this. I would probably just go with `@user.payment.select{|e|e.id}.last`. `@user.payment.select{|e|e.id}` will filter the payments to give you only that ones that has their `id` field set - that means, only records that were saved to the database. That means that command will choose the last saved record(ignoring the blank one), and that is the one you need.